# Monorepo and problem with building packages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg, craco

I try to build modular React application using monorepository (workspaces) - in root folder I have package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": ["shared/react-components", "client/react-app"],
  "scripts": {
    "start": "yarn --cwd shared/react-components build && yarn --cwd client/react-app start"
  }
}
```

I want to include shared/react-components (named e.g. as @shared/react-components), into client/react-app but before I need to compile shared module, and at this place I get nasty error:
`Error: 'default' is not exported by ../../node_modules/deepmerge/dist/cjs.js, imported by src/styles/dark.ts`

I ran yarn install before so deepmerge is available in /node_modules. If I remove workspaces configuration and run: yarn install && yarn build in shared/react-components everything works, so it seems that problem is in workspaces configuration.

Build script in shared/react-components is: `rollup -c`

Any idea what could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a problem was with deepmerge package and TSX, the long thread about problems with importing can be found here: https://github.com/TehShrike/deepmerge/issues/87 I replaced it with lodash merge, and my packages were build again.